# Office add-in - Ribbon FunctionName does not seem to support calling a method from class

Tags: office365api, office365-apps, office-js

In the ribbon manifest, I can declare a function to execute when a ribbon button is clicked. For example,

```
      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
          <FunctionName>doSomething</FunctionName>
      </Action>
```

However, if I have a typescript file that has the following definition:

```
   class MyFunctions {
        public static doSomething(){
           Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://localhost:44337/index.html",
           { height: 50, width: 50 }
        }
    }
```

The following would not work:

```
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>MyFunctions.doSomething</FunctionName>
</Action>
```

It's as if it does not recognize dotted names in the manifest file which in this case is ClassName.FunctionName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyFunctions.doSomething doesn't work because TypeScript compiler translates to it to a function (i.e. typeof MyFunctions == 'function')

Currently Office Add-in manifest only supports:

1. Execute a global function
2. Execute a member function within an "object".

Therefore, if MyFunctions is an object, the manifest will work. Here is one example:

```
var MyFunctions = {
    doSomething: function() {}
};
```

Hopefully this problem will be fixed in the next release. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Functions called by add-in commands must be global for now. In your case the function doesn't execute because it's defined as part of the MyFunctions class.

We realize it makes sense to permit the structure you describe here, so we're working on a fix to allow it in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the info!